# work-queue:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///

Tags: jsp, http

[image]

I am getting error when i am trying to display a image on my jsp page.

JSP Work

```
    <span style="display:inline-block ">


                                                                                <span id="kycDetails"></span>
                                                                                <span id="kycSoftlink"></span>



                                                                        </span>
```

Comment: can you post the .jsp file?

Comment: @SergeiBednar Please check jsp page work posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load the image using `file://`. That isn't possible. You need to put the image on a `http://` or `https://` location.

Comment: V sorry its not question. i did not change

Comment: @Shekhar Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: i mean my  question is i am already store that path in database which location is not change and not modified.

Comment: @Shekhar You can not load an image from a database directly. You need to put it on a HTTP server first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load local resources, you need to make a server or load resources from the internet.